# Sci-fi book about two people living inside a giant's head

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find a sci-fi book from the late '60s or early '70s.

It was set in a world of race of alien giants.

It was about two scientists (man and woman) living in the giant's head. I remember the front cover showing the internal structure of the living quarters (in the giants head) and a person sitting in a chair with large loom of cables attach to a headset they were wearing.

Comment: Hi Jon. Are there any other details you can remember? It's worth writing down everything you can remember as you never know when some apparently minor detail will trigger someone's memory. At the moment apart from the cover you haven't given us much to go on.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This sounds like [*Gold the Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7253) (1971) by Joseph L. Green.  After an attack by unknown aliens, referred to as "Exterminators," a single 300-foot-tall alien is captured.  Two genetically-augmented humans, the titular Gold and the Russian Marina Syerov are sent to the Hilt-Sil homeworld in a small capsule built into the eye socket and brain of the (injured but not dead) alien.  The cover seems to match what you recall:

[image: Paperback cover of "Gold the Man"]

Wikipedia has a partial [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_the_Man) of the beginning of the story:

> "Gold" is a man created using genetic engineering. The object was to produce a person of high intelligence with superhuman reflexes and muscular coordination. He leads an unfulfilled life, despite having become rich and famous, including a career as a concert pianist. He lacks real companionship, and is certain that he is sterile and cannot have children. He is widely regarded as a playboy who has wasted his potential.
>
> Gold lives in America, in a world governed by the United Nations. Humanity has been under attack by an extraterrestrial race they know only as Exterminators, having never seen an individual. The conflict has resulted in one of the enemy ships crashing on the Moon. The sole survivor is a humanoid giant, who was brain-damaged due to lack of oxygen. Evidently the Exterminators are a race of giants. Compared to them, humans are about the size of a large insect.
>
> The Russians also have a genetic superman, Pavel Petrovna. He has built a capsule inside the giant's head, with the ability to control its body's movements from a keyboard while observing the world through one of the eyes. Petrovna himself is deformed, with arms and legs too short for his body. Only Gold has the ability to operate the controls. The plan is for Gold and Petrovna to be installed in the capsule inside the giant, and await rescue. The giant will taken back to his home world, allowing the humans to gain intelligence about their attackers.
>
> When Petrovna is killed in an accident on the Moon, the project has to go ahead with his assistant and lover, Marina Syerov, who initially despises Gold.